# Parsing JSON object in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, parsing

I am getting API response as:

```
[{"subject1": "English", "subject1": "Maths"}]
```

I want to store the values (`English` and `Maths`) into an array without keys like:

```
subject = ["English", "Maths"]
```

Comment: I think you mean `[{"subject1":"English"}, {"subject1":"Maths"}]`?

Comment: If the given JSON is correct, you will not be able to get both "English" and "maths" as you want due to them having the same key on the same object.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this solve your problem:

```js
// if you have variable number of subject
let res =  [{"subject1":"English", "subject2":"Maths"}]

let subjects = []

for(prop in res[0]){
  subjects.push(res[0][prop])
}
console.log(subjects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
subject = [];
subject.push(Object.values(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of objects:

```
[{"subject1":"English"}, {"subject1":"Maths"}]
```

Use this:

```
let res = foo.map(e => e.subject1)
console.log(res) // prints ["English", "Maths"]
```